# Extract common code to enable/disable, show/hide controls on some condition

Tags: c#

I have few controls on my page which I want to show/hide and/or enable/disable on some condition.

Images to help illustrate the requirements:

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2] 
[image: screenshot3]

Following is the code to show/hide, enable/disable the controls. Please review it and tell me how I can extract common code.
Any other suggestion are also more than welcome.

```
// Change controls status (enable/disable, show/hide) on the basis of selected item
protected void ddlLocationType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int locationType = 0;
    int.TryParse(ddlLocationType.SelectedItem.Value, out locationType);

    EnableRelavantLocaitonControls(locationType);
}

private void EnableRelavantLocaitonControls(int locationType)
{
    switch (locationType)
    {
    case 0:
        DefaultControlsPosition();
        break;
    case 1:
        EnableControlsForProvince();
        break;
    case 2:
        EnableControlsForDistrict();
        break;
    case 3:
        EnableControlsForTehsil();
        break;
    case 4:
        EnableControlsForUC();
        break;
    case 6:
        EnableControlsForVillage();
        break;
    default:
        DefaultControlsPosition();
        break;
    }
}

// Show all drop downs.
// Hide all textboxes and disable all controls.
private void DefaultControlsPosition()
{
    ddlProvince.Enabled = false;
    ddlProvince.Visible = true;
    txtProvince.Enabled = false;
    txtProvince.Visible = false;

    ddlDistrict.Enabled = false;
    ddlDistrict.Visible = true;
    ddlDistrict.Enabled = false;
    txtDistrict.Visible = false;

    ddlTehsil.Enabled = false;
    ddlTehsil.Visible = true;
    txtTehsil.Enabled = false;
    txtTehsil.Visible = false;

    ddlUC.Enabled = false;
    ddlUC.Visible = true;
    txtUC.Enabled = false;
    txtUC.Visible = false;

    ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
    ddlVillage.Visible = true;
    txtVillage.Enabled = false;
    txtVillage.Visible = false;
}

// Show all drop downs except province drop down and disable all.
// Show and enable TextBox for province instead of drop down so user can 
// enter name of province.
private void EnableControlsForProvince()
{
    ddlProvince.Enabled = false;
    ddlProvince.Visible = false;
    txtProvince.Enabled = true;
    txtProvince.Visible = true;

    ddlDistrict.Enabled = false;
    ddlDistrict.Visible = true;
    ddlDistrict.Enabled = false;
    txtDistrict.Visible = false;

    ddlTehsil.Enabled = false;
    ddlTehsil.Visible = true;
    txtTehsil.Enabled = false;
    txtTehsil.Visible = false;

    ddlUC.Enabled = false;
    ddlUC.Visible = true;
    txtUC.Enabled = false;
    txtUC.Visible = false;

    ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
    ddlVillage.Visible = true;
    txtVillage.Enabled = false;
    txtVillage.Visible = false;
}

// Show and Enable 'Province' drop down.
// Hide and Disable 'District' drop down.
// Show and Enable 'District' text box.
// Show and Disable all other drop downs beneath District.
private void EnableControlsForDistrict()
{
    ddlProvince.Enabled = true;
    ddlProvince.Visible = true;
    txtProvince.Enabled = false;
    txtProvince.Visible = false;

    ddlDistrict.Enabled = false;
    ddlDistrict.Visible = false;
    txtDistrict.Enabled = true;
    txtDistrict.Visible = true;

    ddlTehsil.Enabled = false;
    ddlTehsil.Visible = true;
    txtTehsil.Enabled = false;
    txtTehsil.Visible = false;

    ddlUC.Enabled = false;
    ddlUC.Visible = true;
    txtUC.Enabled = false;
    txtUC.Visible = false;

    ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
    ddlVillage.Visible = true;
    txtVillage.Enabled = false;
    txtVillage.Visible = false;
}

private void EnableControlsForTehsil()
{
    ddlProvince.Enabled = true;
    ddlProvince.Visible = true;
    txtProvince.Enabled = false;
    txtProvince.Visible = false;

    ddlDistrict.Enabled = true;
    ddlDistrict.Visible = true;
    txtDistrict.Enabled = false;
    txtDistrict.Visible = false;

    ddlTehsil.Enabled = false;
    ddlTehsil.Visible = false;
    txtTehsil.Enabled = true;
    txtTehsil.Visible = true;

    ddlUC.Enabled = false;
    ddlUC.Visible = true;
    txtUC.Enabled = false;
    txtUC.Visible = false;

    ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
    ddlVillage.Visible = true;
    txtVillage.Enabled = false;
    txtVillage.Visible = false;
}

private void EnableControlsForUC()
{
    ddlProvince.Enabled = true;
    ddlProvince.Visible = true;
    txtProvince.Enabled = false;
    txtProvince.Visible = false;

    ddlDistrict.Enabled = true;
    ddlDistrict.Visible = true;
    txtDistrict.Enabled = false;
    txtDistrict.Visible = false;

    ddlTehsil.Enabled = true;
    ddlTehsil.Visible = true;
    txtTehsil.Enabled = false;
    txtTehsil.Visible = false;

    ddlUC.Enabled = false;
    ddlUC.Visible = false;
    txtUC.Enabled = true;
    txtUC.Visible = true;

    ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
    ddlVillage.Visible = true;
    txtVillage.Enabled = false;
    txtVillage.Visible = false;
}

private void EnableControlsForVillage()
{
    ddlProvince.Enabled = true;
    ddlProvince.Visible = true;
    txtProvince.Enabled = false;
    txtProvince.Visible = false;

    ddlDistrict.Enabled = true;
    ddlDistrict.Visible = true;
    txtDistrict.Enabled = false;
    txtDistrict.Visible = false;

    ddlTehsil.Enabled = true;
    ddlTehsil.Visible = true;
    txtTehsil.Enabled = false;
    txtTehsil.Visible = false;

    ddlUC.Enabled = true;
    ddlUC.Visible = true;
    txtUC.Enabled = false;
    txtUC.Visible = false;

    ddlVillage.Enabled = false;
    ddlVillage.Visible = false;
    txtVillage.Enabled = true;
    txtVillage.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to put your requirements in words here or a embedded picure... you can't expect us to click through your links just to figure out what you're doing...

Answer (score 4):

First possible refactoring: define an enumeration for the three possible states

```
enum InputState{
    Hidden,
    Disabled,
    Enabled
}
```

and use it with an extension method (or by extending the class)

```
public static void SetVisibility(this Control ctrl, InputState state){
    switch(state){
        case InputState.Hidden:
            ctrl.Enabled = false;
            ctrl.Visible = false;
            break;
        case InputState.Disabled:
            ctrl.Enabled = false;
            ctrl.Visible = true;
            break;
        case InputState.Enabled:
            ctrl.Enabled = true;
            ctrl.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Start by creating a list of objects which contain the connection between a **location type** and the relevant **controls**. First create a new class to hold this information:

   ```
   public enum LocationType
   {
       Undefined = 0,
       Province = 1,
       District = 2,
       ...
   }

   public class LocationControl
   {
       public LocationType Type { get; set; }
       public TextBox TextBox { get; set; }
       public ComboBox ComboBox { get; set; }
   }

   private List<LocationControl> _myControls = new List<LocationControl>();
   ```
2. Then, create type-control links:

   ```
   private void InitControls()
   {
       // a better approach might be to create all controls here,
       // but if you want to use the VS designer, this will do
       // (just call it inside OnLoad or something)

       _myControls.Add(new LocationControl()
           {
               Type = LocationType.Province,
               TextBox = txtProvince,
               ComboBox = ddlProvince
           });

       _myControls.Add(new LocationControl()
           {
               Type = LocationType.District,
               TextBox = txtDistrict,
               ComboBox = ddlDistrict
           });

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Once you have this information, enabling the right control is trivial:

   ```
   private void EnableRelevantLocationControls(LocationType type)
   {
       // enable this input
       var activeLocation = _myControls.Find(c => c.Type == type);
       Enable(activeLocation);

       // disable all other inputs
       var inactiveLocations = _myControls.Where(c => c.Type != type);
       foreach (var location in inactiveLocations)
           Disable(location);
   }
   ```